# Amazon S3 + Lambda (Node.JS) clarification on the s3.upload() method

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am following [this](https://dev.to/nerychucuy/unzip-large-files-in-aws-using-lambda-and-node-js-cpp) tutorial wherein the programmer used this code:

```
await s3
      .upload({ Bucket: bucket, Key: target_filename, Body: file_stream })
      .promise();
```

Now, I understand that the method above would use the initialized variables `file_stream`, `bucket`, and `target_filename` (which he didn't bother typing out in his tutorial).

But the tutorial is hard to follow since (for what I know) the `Key` parameter inside the upload is the actual directory of the file to be re-uploaded back to S3.

This is confusing because at the `file_stream` variable, another `Key` parameter exists inside the method `getObject()`.

So, is the `filename` inside the `getObject()` method should be the same as `target_filename` of the `upload()` method? and can you initialize the variables mentioned just to make it clearer for this question? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `filename` inside the `getObject()` method may not be the same as the `target_filename` in `upload()`. Let's look at a concrete example. Suppose you have a `photo.zip` file stored on S3 and its key is `a/b/photo.zip`, and you want to unzip it and reupload it to `c/d/photo.jpg` assuming that the `photo.zip` only contains one file. Then, the `filename` should be `a/b/photo.zip`, and the `target_filename` should be `c/d/photo.jpg`. As you can see, they are clearly different.

Comment: in regards to the `target_filename`, it should still indicate a filename and a file extension?

Comment: @monkeybanana No, you can name it whatever you want. It's just an example.

Comment: but how should I unzip or use the `target_filename` if the content of a zip file is multiple files that are not (using the concrete example you use) `photo.jpg`?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What's the usecase?

Comment: The `target_filename` should upload the same filename and file type inside the zip folder it comes from. But the problem with the tutorial is that it does not use a concrete variable example on how to use that. it just says **"initialize the variables here"**

Comment: Also, I don't want my newly unzipped files to be renamed into `target_filename`, I just want it to retain the variable name it has, assuming that the zip file contains multiple files inside.

Comment: Ok, it's possible. You can follow [this example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzipper#parse-zip-by-piping-entries-downstream) and get the file names in the zip file.